# ASP.NET MVC: Should I pass primitives to my actions or should I use Model Binders?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm finding that the code that I write in my controllers is largely repetitive , and more importantly that the tests I write for my controllers are also very repetitive. The general pattern for a save method is as follows...

Take an entity, and a number of primitive parameters. Write the values from the primitive parameters onto the same named parameters on my entity. Validate the entity. Save the entity if it is valid.

I already have a model binder that will bind anything that inherits from IDataEntity (an interface that all our database persisted entities implement). This model binder finds the appropriate repository and looks up the entity with the passed id.

I have been considering adding an extension to this model binder that will also pull the values in from the value provider and write them over the existing values. This will save me some repetitive code in my actions assigning values to my entities. And will also allow me to just pass entities to my controller tests rather than a large number of values.

for example a method that currently looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult SaveCompanyAddress(Address address,
        string address1,
        string address2,
        string address3,
        string city,
        string county,
        Country country,
        string postcode)
    {
        address.Address1 = address1;
        address.Address2 = address2;
        address.Address3 = address3;
        address.City = city;
        address.County = county;
        address.Country = country;
        address.Postcode = postcode;

        Validate(address);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var tran = TransactionFactory.CreateTransaction())
            {
                addressRepository.Save(entity);
                tran.Commit();
            }

            return this.RedirectToAction(x => x.List(address.Company));
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Edit", address);
        }
    }
```

Would be halved in length and have nearly all its arguments removed. This certainly sounds appealing as the amount of code we write is reduced, and a test to test validation can pass a mock validation provider and default address and not worry about setting all those parameters. but I am worried that there might be a little too much behind the scenes magic to make it a good idea.

Thoughts? Opnions? Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also compromise and use the default model binder to bind your simple properties and get the complex properties from the value provider and fill them in "manually."  For a model with only simple properties the default model binder would be sufficient.  For those with one or two complex properties, those which aren't handled by the default model binder, you could still save significant amounts of code without having to write the custom model binder. The complex binding code could be written using shared methods on a class.  Once the binding code in your controller needs to cross controller boundaries or becomes significant, refactor it into your custom model binder.

Comment: The reason that a custom model binder is needed is that I have to look up the entity in the DB first. And then use default model binder style binding to set the values onto its properties. This allows my save to update my existing entities easily. I'm sure it would be possible to hand off the property binding to the default model binder.

Comment: You can still use TryUpdateModel/UpdateModel for simple properties and manually update the complex properties using values from the ValueProvider when updating an existing model.  That is, have your method take the primary key of the model as a parameter, retrieve the model using the key, use Try/UpdateModel to update simple properties and handle the complex properties manually.  Eventually, you may find that you do need a custom model binder (or have written most of it already) and can then refactor to it.